# Extracting coefficients from sym into matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, coefficients

I have a symbolic vector like this:

```
du = [3u11 - 1u12, 8*u12 - u11 - 3*u14, 4*u13 - 5*u14, 11*u14 - 12*u13 - 8*u12]
```

I then want to extract the coefficients, I can do that with the `coeffs` function, e.g.

```
coeffs(du(:,1))
```

which returns `[3, -1]`.

I want to do this with a `for` loop and then insert the coefficients into a matrix. In this example, the matrix would be 4-by-4, so I would preload it with `C = zeros(4)`. The coefficients, `[3,-1]`, would then be placed in `C(1,1)` and `C(1,2)`, respectively, whereas `coeffs(du(:,2)`, which returns `[8, -1 -3]`, would be placed in `C(2,2)`, `C(2,1)`, and `C(2,4)`. Thus, the row in `du` would correspond to the row in `C`, and the second number in each coefficient name, e.g., `u12`, would correspond to the column.

Ok, here's my code:

```
clc, clear all
k=[1,2,3,4,5];
nodes= [1 2; 2 4; 2 4;2 4; 4 3];
nnodes=4;
nelem=5;

u=sym('u%d%d',[1 nnodes]);

f(u)=sym('f(u)');
f(u)=0;
for i=1:nelem
f=f+0.5*k(i)*(u(nodes(i,2))-u(nodes(i,1)))^2;
end
for i=1:nnodes
du(i)=diff(f,u(i),1);
end
```

So I'm not sure how to make a matrix out of the coefficients of du

Comment: Oh, it doesn't look like the code formatted properly, so sorry!

Comment: What is the actual question? Please show use your actual code where you do this. Make sure that it is runnable by others, i.e., all variables/functions/inputs defined. Indicate what the expected output is and any issues in full.

Comment: I tried to clarify some things with my edit. Hopefully I got it all right. Also, `coeffs(du(:,1))=[3,-1]` is not valid code as `[3,-1]` is the return value. You still need to ask an actual question and show your code.

Comment: I added my code. I'm not sure how I can create a matrix out of the symbolic expression and still get the coefficients in the right place